# Web definition and webtemplate and site defintion and site template in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can any one explain what are Web definition and webtemplate and site defintion and site template in sharepoint 2010

Regards,
Suresh Pydi

Answer (score 2):

**Site Definitions**

- A site definition is the core definition of what a site is in SharePoint.
- A site definition is installed on file system of web front ends, located at ..\12\Template\SiteTemplates. This directory is language-neutral.
- A site definition consists of .aspx pages and .xml files with
  Collaborative Application Mark-up Language (CAML).
- A major benefit is that the Page and List definition is read locally
  from the file system, not from Content Database.

**Site Template**

- A site template (*.stp file) is created through the user interface or
  through implementation of the object model.
- The site template package is a package containing a set of
  differences and changes from a base site definition.
- The site template package is stored as a CAB-based file that can be
  downloaded or uploaded to site collections by users with the
  appropriate rights.

For more details you can check these link out
[Site Definition Vs Site tempalte](http://www.dhirendrayadav.com/2010/09/site-template-vs-site-definition.html)

Answer (score 0):

WebTemplates and Site Definitions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434313.aspx

Deciding Between Custom Web Templates and Custom Site Definitions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979683.aspx

Site Definitions vs. Web Templates

http://sharepointchick.com/archive/0001/01/01/site-definitions-vs.-webtemplates.aspx

> A site definition is the basic blueprint for a site, including how it
>   looks, what lists it contains, default navigational structures, and so
>   on. You normally create a site definition by hand-editing CAML.
>
> A site template can be created from within the Sharepoint application,
>   and is basically a "diff" between the site definition and any changes
>   made since the site was created. A site template is based on the
>   underlying site definition, which means that if you create a new site
>   from a template, and later change the underlying site definition, you
>   run the very real risk of irreversibly screwing up your site.
>
> A best practice is to configure a minimal site definition that, once
>   created, is never modified again, and use site templates to store
>   reusable customizations.

Above taken from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386016/what-is-the-main-differences-between-site-definition-and-site-template

Site Features vs Site Templates vs Site Definitions

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2007Dev/Pages/Site%20Features%20vs%20Site%20Templates%20vs%20Site%20Definitions.aspx

I hope this helps!